# Appendix in Latex.

Tags: appendices

I am creating an appendix in report format.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\include{chapter1} %chapter 1
\include{chapter2} %chapter 2
\include{chapter3} %chapter 3
\include{chapter4} %chapter 4
\include{chapter5} %chapter 5
\include{chapter6} %chapter 6
\include{chapter8} %chapter 8
\include{chapter9} %chapter 9
\include{chapter10}%chapter 10
\include{acknowledgement}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
 \bibliography{mybib2}
 \appendix
 \chapter{title}
 \include{chapter7} %chapter 7
\end{document}
```

However, output is showing flush right. [image]

Please suggest some solution. I tried writing \justifying  in that chapter. I got error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suspect something is wrong in the code in `acknowledgement.tex`

Comment: \chapter{Mathematics for fractional calculus} 
\label{ch7}

\section{{Gamma function}}
The Gamma function is defined by the following equation, which is useful as factorial is not defined for all real numbers \cite{Milton1972},
\begin{equation}
\Gamma (x)= \int_{0}^{\infty}  t^{^{x-1}}e^{-t}dt,   \Re(Z)>0
\end{equation}

Some properties of gamma function

Comment: If I include this appendix as chapter, there is no problem. Problem only during appendix.

Comment: I mentioned `acknowledgement.tex`; can you show its contents by doing an edit to your question?

Comment: Hi, It worked.  I used flush right in acknowledgment. \flushright{\textbf{Pritesh Shah}}, I commented this line. Now, it is working. Thanks.  How can I use flush right in acknowledgment?

Comment: `\flushright` is not a command with an argument. What you want is `\begin{flushright}\textbf{Pritesh Shah}\end{flushright}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common error to think that in order to flush right some words one does

```
\flushright{some words}
```

This is a *very big* mistake:

1. `flushright` is an environment
2. Even if `\flushright` by itself produces no error, it will set up ragged left typesetting forever

In your case, the bibliography stopped this because of how the `thebibliography` environment works, but as soon as the bibliography ends, ragged left typesetting as ordered by issuing `\flushright` resumes.

Solution: do

```
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{Pritesh Shah}
\end{flushright}
```

instead.